# how to get the session cookies using volley library in android studio?

Tags: android-studio, http, session, cookies, android-volley

I am making an android app in android studio (java) that uses the rest API to get and post data.
I can log in and signup to the server but in order to get the data from the server I need the session cookies, but I don't know how to get session cookies using the volley library.

Here is my working code for the login:-

```
private void login(String email,String password){
        String url = "https://someURL.com/login";

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                textView.setText("String Response : "+ response.toString());
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                textView.setText("error");
            }
        }){
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("email",email);
                params.put("password",password);
                return params;
            }
        };

        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }
```

And here is my request code:-

```
    private void getProfile(String id,String email,String password){
        String url = "https://someURL.com/profile/:"+id;

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                textView.setText("String Response : "+ response.toString());
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                textView.setText("Profile error");
            }
        });

        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }
```

Both are working fine but in order to get the data from the server, I need to create a cookie-based session. Please help ... I have searched for the resources but nothing worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem (by going through the documentation and source code of the volley library).
The solution I got is not an automatic way of handling the session cookies, instead, it is solved by overriding some methods of Volley.
My problem is how to get the session cookies and then how to set the session cookies(I know it is a novice way of saying and not technically right - read further for clarity) for further requests.

I solved my first problem by overriding the 'parseNetworkResponse' method of Volley. This method has a 'response' parameter which can give all the headers of the response from the server by using 'response.headers'.
Below is my code:-

```
            @Override
            protected Response<String> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
                Map<String, String> responseHeaders = response.headers;
                cookie = new String(responseHeaders.get("Set-Cookie"));
                Log.i("cookies",cookie);
                jsonObject = new JSONObject(response.headers);
                Log.i("response", String.valueOf(jsonObject));
                return super.parseNetworkResponse(response);
            }
```

And for my second problem, I overloaded the 'getHeaders' method. This method can be used to send the cookie back to the server for any query which is authentication-based.

Below is my code:-

```
            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String,String> headers = new HashMap<>();
                try {
                    headers.put("cookie",String.valueOf(jsonObject.get("Set-Cookie")));
                    Log.i("header created ",headers.toString());
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return headers;
            }
```

*Do check your response cookies before applying to the code from any API testing application.

And also for any further explanation. I was searching for the solution for more than 10 days.